# Is it possible to generate a parser for a language using the Reverse Polish notation with bison/yacc?

Tags: c++, yacc, bison

Is it possible to generate a parser for a scripting language that uses the Reverse Polish notation (and a Postscript-like syntax) using bison/yacc?

The parser should be able to parse code similar to the following one:

```
/fib
{
  dup dup 1 eq exch 0 eq or not
  {
    dup 1 sub fib
    exch 2 sub fib
    add
  } if
} def
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Postscript`? Are you referring to the postscript language or are you referring to something else slightly more abstract?

Comment: With Postscript-like programming language I mean a stack oriented programming language like Postscript is.

Comment: When you say 'Postscript' I think of the printer language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript. But what I think you mean 'What I would call a stack based reverse polish language': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language But don't take that to mean 'I think you're description is wrong' its just the way i am thinking and want to clarify (for myself).

Comment: I see now. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language#PostScript_stacks I found your example on wikipedia. Sometimes its easier to include a link than to try and describe it.

Comment: @Martin York: I should better describe the language as one using the Reverse Polish notation, rather than saying that is stack based; the point of the question is that the used notation is not the Infix notation.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the example on using Bison is an RPN calculator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the short description above and the notes on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language#PostScript_stacks

A simple bison grammer for the above could be:

```
%token          ADD
%token          DUP
%token          DEF
%token          EQ
%token          EXCH
%token          IF
%token          NOT
%token          OR
%token          SUB
%token          NUMBER
%token          IDENTIFIER

%%


program         :   action_list_opt
action_list_opt :   action_list
                |                           /* No Action */
action_list     :   action
                |   action_list action
action          :   param_list_opt operator
param_list_opt  :   param_list
                |                           /* No Parameters */
param_list      :   param
                |   param_list param
param           :   literal
                |   name
                |   action_block

operator        :   ADD
                |   DUP
                |   DEF
                |   EQ
                |   EXCH
                |   IF
                |   NOT
                |   OR
                |   SUB

literal         :   NUMBER
name            :   '/' IDENTIFIER
action_block    :   '{' program '}'


%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming you mean one that also uses postscript notation, it means you'd define your expressions something like:

```
expression: operand operand operator
```

Rather than the more common infix notation:

```
expression: operand operator operand
```

but that hardly qualifies as a big deal. If you mean something else by "Postcript-like", you'll probably have to clarify before a better answer can be given.

Edit: Allowing an arbitrary number of operands and operators is also pretty easy:

```
operand_list: 
            | operand_list operand
            ;

operator_list: 
             | operator_list operator
             ;

expression: operand_list operator_list
          ;
```

As it stands, this doesn't attempt to enforce the proper number of operators being present for any particular operand -- you'd have to add those checks separately. In a typical case, a postscript notation is executed on a stack machine, so most such checks become simple stack checks.

I should add that although you certainly *can* write such parsers in something like yacc, languages using postscript notation generally require such minimal parsing that you frequently feed them directly to some sort of virtual machine interpreter that executes them quite directly, with minimal parsing (mostly, the parsing comes down to throwing an error if you attempt to use a name that hasn't been defined).

Comment: The problem is that also `operand operand operand operand operator operator` is allowed.

Comment: I take that it would be possible to generate a parser using yacc, but it would be an overkill for a scripting language with a syntax similar to Postscript. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No. If it works for a compiled language then it should be just as useful for an interpreted language (scripting language). I don't think it is overkill (actually I think it is essential as writing it by hand is both hard and error prone).

Comment: @Martin: Actually, no, in this case writing it by hand is relatively easy. Basically, you have a mixture of operands and operators. Operands push a value into the stack, and operators take some number of operands from the stack, combine them, and put a result back on the stack. As such, "parsing" is basically just looking a token up in a dictionary to see if it's defined. If not, you reject it.

Comment: @ Jerry Coffin: OK. I give you that. It does look simple enough to write a hand written one.